Inequality involving finite number of nonnegative real numbers
If $0\leq c_k\leq 1$ and $n$ is any positive integer, then is
$$\frac{n\prod_{k=1}^nc_k}{1+n\prod_{k=1}^nc_k}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{c_k}{1+c_k}?$$
It is true for at least one of the $c_k=0$ and is also true if  all $c_k'$s are equal. Please suggest if this inequality already exists in the literature.

This can be simplified to be: $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+c_k}\leq n-1+\frac1{1+n\prod_k c_k}.$$ Not sure if that helps any.

This version is also  nice!

I do not know whether this inequality has a unique name, but we can prove this.
From your observation, it is enough to assume that each $c_k$ lies in $(0,1]$.
Now, consider $x_k = (c_k)^{-1} \in [1,\infty)$.
Then, the given inequality is equivalent to:
$$
n \cdot \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+x_k} \right)^{-1} \leq n + \prod_{k=1}^n x_k\,.
$$
To show the above inequality, observe from AM-HM inequality that:
$$
n \cdot \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+x_k} \right)^{-1} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\,.
$$
WLOG, let $x_1 = M \geq 1$ is maximum over $(x_k)_{k=1}^n$. Then
$$
1 + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \leq 1 + M < n + M \leq  n + M\cdot\prod_{k=2}^n x_k\,,
$$
since $x_k \geq 1$.

Update
Somewhat tighter inequality would be:
$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^nc_k}{1+\prod_{k=1}^nc_k}\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{c_k}{1+c_k}$$
where $c_k \in [0,1]$ for $k\in [n]$. Equality condition is $c_k=1\, \forall k$ or $c_k=0 \,\forall k$.
